# C# Skip or stop next function

Tags: c#, function, skip

I have a button. One button has three functions and I want skip last function when there is a case of function one or two.

I have tried return; but nothing. or it disables everything, or still doing its thing

Here is example:

```
     private bool functionOne() 
     {
        if (blah blah == "" || blah blah2 == "" || blah blah3 == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("text");
            return true;
        }
        try
        {

            if (count == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Text");
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private bool functionTwo() 
    {
        if (blah blah == "" || blah blah2 == "" || blah blah3 == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("text");
            return true;
        }
        try
        {

            if (count == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("text");
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void functionThree() 
    {
        if (blah blah == "" || blah blah2 == "" || blah blah3 == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("text");
            return true;
        }
        try
        {

            if (count == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Text");
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }


     private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
       bool result1 = functionOne();
       bool result2 = functionTwo();
       if (result1|| result2) functionThree();
    }
```

What should I add into Function one and Two at the end instead of return; so that I can skip FunctionThree at all?

Comment: is this the real code you are using or a verified version of it? if without any condition, ...

Comment: It is not an actual code. It is example in order how I have it in my code. I just want to know how to prevent Function1 and Function2 from carrying on to Function3

Comment: Return just exits the current method, it does nothing to the calling method

Answer (score 1):

Change the first two functions to return a boolean result, so that you can do this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   bool result1 = FunctionOne()
   bool result2 = FunctionTwo()
   if (result1 || result2) FunctionThree()
}
```

---

Example of how to modify the `FunctionOne` and `FunctionTwo`:

```
private bool FunctionOne()
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Something One?", "Caption", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: then you should modify `Function1` and `Function2` to return a boolean

Comment: cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'bool'

Comment: Ok, I tried to do as you suggested but  if (result1 || result2) FunctionThree() doesnt work. It highlights result1 and result 2

Comment: Can anyone show me how would it look like in a code?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Could you check why I am getting on FunctionOne and FunctionTwo highlight this message: Not all code paths return a value